# user contributed content as custom post types

Tags: posts, customization

We are looking into creating a solution that allows user to contribute media files by filling out a form (without access to the admin) and have it ןד created as a custom post type. 
The files will be either YouTube Movies, PowerPoint Files etc.
Is that possible at all? Do you know any example of something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is pretty easy using something like [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/)